# Unity JSON loading Image path syntax

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

Hi I would like to know what is the proper syntax to load image on JSON to UNITY.
I have no experience in Unity and C Sharp JSON encoding can someone give the syntax of loading image on JSON to Unity? Thank you

Comment: Don't duplicate this please those duplicates are also my questions lol no one's answering my questions

Comment: Please do not ask the-same question multiple times. I had to close 2 and leave one open. The reason you are not getting answers is not because your question is hard.It's because it doesn't make sense. Please go the other question that is still open, edit it and explain what exactly you are doing, the current problem and what that code is currently doing. *"load image on JSON"* that doesn't make sense. I would be good if you google and read what json is then careful modiy the other question

Comment: I'm just asking is what is the proper way for the JSON to access images. that's it. I'm just new to this platform and I need to finish my project.

Comment: *"the proper way for the JSON to access images"* I still don't think you know what json is. Please see my advice about googling it above.

Comment: Give me a hint of what is JSON is please sir,